# Validation error with django formsets (blank fields not accepted)

Tags: python, django

I have two models (Workout and ExerciseSet) that are connected in a One to Many relationship. I'm trying to use a CreateView to build a form that allows me to create a workout and exercise set(s) at the same time. The thing is when I only have one exercise set field (extra=1 in the inlineformset_factory), it works - but when I want to set extra to a larger number like 3, it will only work if all the workouts are set up. Otherwise it throws a `null value in column "repetitions" violates not-null constraint` error.

I'm thinking of overwriting the clean method in the inlineformset class to solve this, but when I call super.clean(), it keeps returning None. Just wondering if anyone could help.

EDIT - I made changes suggested to include blank=True and null=True to the model fields. I can get it to work by moving the validation code to the forms, but it seems kinda hackish. Is there a better way to do the validation?

**models.py**

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(
            'Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False
        )

class ExerciseSet(models.Model):
    EXERCISE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('pushup', 'Push Up'),
        ('situp', 'Sit-up')
    )

    workout = models.ForeignKey(
            'Workout', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='exercise_sets'
        )

    repetitions = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    exercise_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=EXERCISE_TYPE_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class WorkoutForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Workout
        exclude = ()

class ExerciseSetForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExerciseSet
        exclude = ()

class CustomExerciseSetInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        print('custom')
        print(cleaned_data)


ExerciseSetFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Workout, ExerciseSet, form=ExerciseSetForm, 
    formset=CustomExerciseSetInlineFormSet, extra=3)
```

**views.py**

```
class WorkoutCreate(CreateView):
    model = Workout
    fields = ['profile', 'created']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        template_name = 'pushup/workout_form.html'

        context['workout_form'] = WorkoutForm()
        context['exercise_set_form'] = ExerciseSetFormSet()

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        workout_form = WorkoutForm(request.POST)
        formset = ExerciseSetFormSet(request.POST)

        if workout_form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            with transaction.atomic():
                workouts_saved = 0
                workout = workout_form.save()

                for exercise_set_form in formset:
                    exercise_set = exercise_set_form.save(commit=False)

                    if exercise_set.repetitions == None or exercise_set.exercise_type == None:
                        continue

                    exercise_set.workout = workout
                    exercise_set.save()
                    workouts_saved += 1

                if workouts_saved == 0:
                    raise ValidationError('No workouts are valid')

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('pushup:workout-detail', kwargs={'pk': workout.pk}))
        else:
            raise Http404
```

Comment: You sould add null=True to model's field: `repetitions = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)`

Comment: Thanks! I added those two and I can now save - I am doing the validation in the view though it seems hackish. Just wondering if there's a better way to do it?

Comment: This is not a hack @neverwalkaloner said a perfect solution and it's pretty standard

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Thank you! I'm still pretty new to django so not sure what's the best way to do things

Comment: Don't worry you should ask if you have some doubts. :)